# MySQL Insert values and some to be selected from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

- works (id, name, date_started, date_finished, type_id, employer_id)
- types (id, type)
- employers (id, name, last_name, company)

I want when inserting into works table records in one query to insert into columns: name, date (by hand), then also into type_id and employer_id columns (selecting id from other tables)

I know you can insert and then use select, but how do i add the other values, that i need to type by hand as they dont exist on other tables?

Comment: An example record would be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put the extra values directly in the `SELECT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO works (name, date_started, type_id, employer_id)
SELECT name, curdate(), type_id, employer_id
FROM types t
JOIN employers e ON ...
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have subqueries inside `VALUES()` clause, provided the subquery will only return one value.

```
INSERT INTO works (name, date_started, date_finished, type_id, employer_id)
VALUES
(
    'name here',
    'date started',
    'date finished',
    (SELECT id FROM types WHERE type = 'val' LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT id FROM employers WHERE name = 'val' LIMIT 1)
)
```